# SQL Server : insert into two tables with case

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have two tables

1. PriceMst
2. ProductMst

When inserting data into `ProductMst`, the code inserts only one value, but in `PriceMst` there is a condition **if price > 300** it would be insert one kg, 750 gms, 500 gms, 250 gms respective calculate there price according to weight that is 1 kg, 750 gms, 500 gms, 250 gms **if price < 300** it should insert only once.

And in `PriceMst` generate some id which take main `Productcode` eg. FP-001 and **generate** **PriceCode  like this  FP-001-01.**

My table description are

tblProduct

```
   ProductCode  ProductName ProductPrize    ProductSizeID
   ------------------------------------------------------
    FP-001          ABC         200.00          4
    FP-002          PQW         500.00          3
    FP-003          ASD        1200.00          4
```

tblPriceMST

```
ProductCode ProductPriceID  ProductPrize    ProductSize  ProductUnit
----------------------------------------------------------------------
 FP-001         FP-001-05    200.00           1             KG
 FP-002         FP-002-01    500.00           1             KG
 FP-002         FP-002-02    375.00         750             GMS
 FP-002         FP-002-03    250.00         500             GMS
 FP-002         FP-002-04    125.00         250             GMS
 FP-003         FP-003-01   1200.00           1             KG
 FP-003         FP-003-02    900.00         750             GMS
 FP-003         FP-003-03    600.00         500             GMS
 FP-003         FP-003-04    300.00         250             GMS
```

Please guide me how to insert in two table in single query.

This query will be used in my stored procedure.

Comment: You can not directly insert into more than one table at once. And you don't need that. Please show what you got in your SP.

Comment: What are you expecting as an answer here? You are talking about calculations but we don't know what those are. And more importantly...why are you storing ProductPrice in two tables??? You seem to have some normalization issues going on here which is probably making this somewhat more difficult than it needs to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to do a couple of things to make this work.  For the first part of your stored procedure you'll need to insert into the tblProduct table, then store the new ProductCode in a variable.  I'm assuming that ProductCode is generated via trigger or computed column.  If you're not automatically generating that, the best way to do that is by [creating a computed column](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/custom-auto-generated-sequences-with-sql-server).

Below you create your procedure with the ProductName and ProductPrice as parameters, insert them into your tblProduct, and store the new ProductCode into a @NewProductCode temp table.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.InsertProduct @ProductName nvarchar(255), @ProductPrice decimal(19,4)
AS
    DECLARE @NewProductCodeTempTable table (ID int)

    INSERT INTO tblProduct (ProductName, ProductPrize) 
    OUTPUT INTO INSERTED.ProductCode @NewProductCode
    VALUES (@ProductName, @ProductPrice)
```

Next you'll use an IF/ELSE statement to determine whether you need to insert one, or 4 records into your tblPriceMST table.

```
    DECLARE @NewProductCode = SELECT ID FROM @NewProductCodeTempTable

    IF (@ProductPrice < 300)   
        INSERT INTO tblPriceMST (ProductCode, ProductPriceID, ProductPrize,    ProductSize, ProductUnit)
        VALUES (@NewProductCode, @NewProductCode + '-01', @ProductPrice, 1, 'KG')
    ELSE 
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO tblPriceMST (ProductCode, ProductPriceID, ProductPrize,    ProductSize, ProductUnit)
        VALUES (@NewProductCode, @NewProductCode + '-01', @ProductPrice, 1, 'KG')

        INSERT INTO tblPriceMST (ProductCode, ProductPriceID, ProductPrize,    ProductSize, ProductUnit)
        VALUES (@NewProductCode, @NewProductCode + '-02', @ProductPrice*.75, 750, 'GMS')   

        INSERT INTO tblPriceMST (ProductCode, ProductPriceID, ProductPrize,    ProductSize, ProductUnit)
        VALUES (@NewProductCode, @NewProductCode + '-03', @ProductPrice*.5, 500, 'GMS')  

        INSERT INTO tblPriceMST (ProductCode, ProductPriceID, ProductPrize,    ProductSize, ProductUnit)
        VALUES (@NewProductCode, @NewProductCode + '-04', @ProductPrice*.25, 250, 'GMS')            
    END
GO
```

I've inferred what your rules are for inserting records for the different product weights if the price is > 300.  But if you have more rules, you would add additional IF/THEN or CASE statements in the ELSE block here.

There may be a much easier way to do this if you simplify your table design but without knowing all of your requirements it would be hard to say what it should look like.

Comment: So, did you succeed in solve this issue? Was my answer of any help?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your ProductSizeID seems to be ignored - is this the intended behaviour? It's not used in the tblPriceMST...

However, if you ALWAYS only need Prize ID 01 for unit 1 KG for all prices < 300 and always Prize ID 2 - 4 for 1 KG to 250 G for all prices >= 300, you could simply use a UNION ALL:

```
SELECT ProductCode, ProductCode+'-01' AS ProductPriceID, ProductPrize, 1 ProductSize, 'KG' ProductUnit
  FROM tblProduct
  WHERE ProductPrize < 300
UNION ALL
SELECT ProductCode, ProductCode+'-01' AS ProductPriceID, ProductPrize, 1 ProductSize, 'KG' ProductUnit
  FROM tblProduct
  WHERE ProductPrize >= 300
UNION ALL
SELECT ProductCode, ProductCode+'-02' AS ProductPriceID, ProductPrize*0.75, 750 ProductSize, 'G' ProductUnit
  FROM tblProduct
  WHERE ProductPrize >= 300
UNION ALL
SELECT ProductCode, ProductCode+'-03' AS ProductPriceID, ProductPrize*0.5, 500 ProductSize, 'G' ProductUnit
  FROM tblProduct
  WHERE ProductPrize >= 300
UNION ALL
SELECT ProductCode, ProductCode+'-04' AS ProductPriceID, ProductPrize*0.25, 250 ProductSize, 'G' ProductUnit
  FROM tblProduct
  WHERE ProductPrize >= 300
ORDER BY 1, 2
```

See SQLFiddle for details: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0910e/7